# Jasmine expect returns Null

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get a origin_name, modify it and then compare to a new name, but protractor keeps me returning me a error. Why?

```
modificaNomeDoLote() {
        const nomeLote = pageObjectBase.obterElementoPorID('nome-lote');
        this.esperarCampoNomeEstarClicavel(nomeLote).then(() => {
            nomeLote.getText().then(nomeAtual => {
                nomeLote.clear().then(() => {
                    nomeLote.sendKeys('Teste Automatizado gerado em ' + pageObjectBase.retonarDataAtual()).then(() => {
                        pageObjectBase.teclaTab();
                        nomeLote.getText().then((nomeModificado) => {
                            expect(nomeAtual).not.toBe(nomeModificado);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

The Error:

> - Expected '' not to be ''.

Comment: the error says both are `''` that's why `.not.toBe` is failing, that's what it was supposed to say.

Comment: But I don't want to return Null.
I want to return the text from my parameter.

Comment: protractor is getting both `''` (empty strings), maybe you need to modify the selectors for those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, protractor always return **null** using **getText** from an **input**.
So I used **getAtrribute('value')** and **works**.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty

Answer (score 0):

You don't store `nomeAtual` in variable, that is a root of your issue. I also prefer if you make decomposition in your one big function, it looks like as kind of mess. Also if you are using `typescript` you probably would like to use `async-await` construction to resolve promises. It could look as:

```
    modificaNomeDoLote async () {
        const nomeLote: ElementFinder = pageObjectBase.obterElementoPorID('nome-lote');
        const someVariable: any = await this.esperarCampoNomeEstarClicavel(nomeLote); 
        const nomeAtual: string = await nomeLote.getText();
        await nomeLote.clear();
        await nomeLote.sendKeys(`Teste Automatizado gerado em ${pageObjectBase.retonarDataAtual()}`;
        await pageObjectBase.teclaTab();
        const nomeModificado: string = await nomeLote.getText()

        expect(nomeAtual).not.toBe(nomeModificado);
}
```